# Google Play badge with https

Tags: https, google-play, badge

I need to integrate on my website a Google Play badge for linking to an Android app on Google Play, with https.

The badge generator offers the badge in http version: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/badges.html.

On the other hand, [this page](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/brand.html) gives the possiblity to download the desired badge.

Google doesn't seem to provide these images with an "https" url, which creates warning on the browser if the user is accessing the website with https.

I was wondering if I am allowed to host the image of the Google badge on the website that is using it, and therefore being able to access the image through https connection when desired.